# Infinite ring with no units

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am slightly confused about the definition of a unit. I know that (Z, +, *) is a ring that is infinite. If Z is not a field, then is Z also an infinite ring with no units since it is not a field?

Comment: Every ring has a unit, since $1$ is a unit in every ring. $\mathbb Z$ has $2$ units, in fact. To be a field, a ring needs two additional things: 1. commutativity of multiplication and 2. the set of units is the set of elements excluding $0$.

Comment: Alright, is there a ring that is infinite such that it has no units?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ has two units: $1$ and $-1$. If you require your rings to have a multiplicative identity, then all rings have units. If you allow rings that don't have a multiplicative identity, then there are both finite rings without units, and infinite rings without units, since to even talk about "units" you must have a multiplicative identity.

Comment: Sure: take the ring consisting of integers with their usual addition, but multiplication $*$ defined by $a*b=0$ for all $a$ and $b$. If you want a ring that has a nontrivial multiplicative structure, take the set of all functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ of compact support (for each $f$ there exists an $M\gt 0$ which may depend on $f$ such that $f$ is $0$ outside of $[-M,M]$), with the usual addition and multiplication of functions as the operations.

Comment: I would like to point out that the word "unit" in the question is unclear. I personally hate the use of "unit" to mean "invertible element", but in any case it should be made clear in the question.

Comment: A field has all non-zero elements as units. A ring which is not a field only requires one non-zero element that is not a unit. All rings have at least one unit, $1,$ under the usual definition of ring. $-1$ is also a unit, but sometimes, $-1=1,$ so this doesn't always give another unit.

Comment: "with no units since it is not a field?" If not all nonzero elements are units, it doesn't mean that there are "NO" units.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring in which not every (non-zero) element is a unit.  That doesn't mean it is wholly without any units at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unit in a ring $R$ is an element $a\in R$ such that there exists an element $b\in R$ with $ab=ba=1$, i.e., $a$ has a multiplicative inverse. If $R$ is not a field, that does not mean that $R$ is unitless. For example, $\mathbb Z$ is a ring with only two units: $1$ and $-1$.

A ring is defined differently depending on the text/author. Some authors require rings to have a multiplicative identity, while others do not make such a requirement.

If a ring *must* have the multiplicative identity $1$, then no rings are unitless, since $1$ is always a unit.

If the multiplicative identity is not a requirement, then  there exist infinite rings that are unitless, e.g., $2\mathbb Z$.